# Making Image same size as window in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

How do I make picture the same size as window. I was trying a lot of stuff but it is just same size. I dont have image in .kv file but in main app. I tried also hint_size(1,1) it didnt work.

```
if(value=="coffee"):
                self.add_widget(Image(source ='coffee.jpg',
                keep_ratio = (True),
                allow_stretch=(True)))
```

Comment: You did indeed try `hint_size(1,1)`, except that it is an incorrect argument and value assignment. Have you tried `size_hint=[1,1]` instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It may work
1st import Windows that will give whole app size
, Then set the size of image.

```
from kivy.core.window import Window

if(value=="coffee"):
                self.add_widget(Image(source ='coffee.jpg',
                keep_ratio = (True),
                allow_stretch=(True),
                size = Window.size))
```